# Section and text left indentation

Tags: indentation, sections-paragraphs

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paper=a4paper}                
\geometry{bindingoffset=1.5cm,hmargin={1.5cm,1.5cm},vmargin={1cm,1cm}}
\geometry{includehead=true,headheight=3cm,headsep=1cm}  
\geometry{includefoot=false}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1-1]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1-1]
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\lipsum[1-1]
\end{document}
```

text output: (bindingoffset 1.5cm + left margin 1.5cm; 3cm total left margin)
[image]

desired output:
[image]

Is possible to make section and text under sections/subsections etc indented by 2 cm?

**edit**
With @Bernard help:
[image]
Is possible to move numbering left; like in my desired output?

**EDIT 2** (also related to question [Combining two macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442698/combining-two-macros?noredirect=1#comment1110923_442698))
Using @Bernard, @ereg and @Henri Menke code and @cfr advice.

**CODE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{paper=a4paper}
\geometry{bindingoffset=1.5cm,hmargin={3.5cm,1.5cm},vmargin={1cm,1cm}}
\geometry{includehead=true,headheight=3cm,headsep=1cm}
\geometry{includefoot=false}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill \textit{Table of Contents}}     %%Table of contents name change
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\hfill \textit{List of Figures}}     %%List of figures name change
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\hfill \textit{List of Tables}}       %%List of tables name change
\newcommand\tocloflot{%
    \clearpage
    \tableofcontents
    \addtocontents{toc}{\hrule height1pt}
    \clearpage
    \csname phantomsection\endcsname
    \listoffigures
    \addtocontents{lof}{\hrule height1pt\par\bigskip}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
    \clearpage
    \csname phantomsection\endcsname
    \listoftables
    \addtocontents{lot}{\hrule height1pt\par\bigskip}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
    \clearpage
}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{\parbox{2cm}{\thesection}}{-0.5pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}{\parbox{2cm}{\thesubsection}}{-0.5pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}{\parbox{2cm}{\thesubsubsection}}{-0.5pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{-2cm}{0.6cm}{0.6cm}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{-2cm}{0.4cm}{0.4cm}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{-2cm}{0.2cm}{0.2cm}

\def\defineEasylist#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname 
    Easylist@style@#1\endcsname{\NewList(#2)}}
\def\Easylist{\futurelet\next\doEasylist}
\def\doEasylist{\ifx[\next\expandafter\doEasylistone\else\expandafter
    \doEasylistnop\fi}
\def\doEasylistone[#1] 
{\begin{easylist}\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\csname 
        Easylist@style@#1\endcsname\fi}
    \def\doEasylistnop{\begin{easylist}\NewList}
        \def\endEasylist{\end{easylist}}

    \defineEasylist{lowercasestyle} 
    {Numbers=l,Hang=true,FinalSpace=0.2cm,Align=fixed, 
        Margin1=0.5cm,Margin2=1.5cm,Margin3=2.5cm,Margin4=3.5cm, 
        Margin5=4.5cm,Margin6=5.5cm,Margin7=6.5cm,Space=0.15cm,Space*=0.15cm}

    \defineEasylist{uppercasestyle} 
    {Numbers=L,Hang=true,FinalSpace=0.2cm,Align=fixed, 
        Margin1=0.5cm,Margin2=1.5cm,Margin3=2.5cm,Margin4=3.5cm, 
        Margin5=4.5cm,Margin6=5.5cm,Margin7=6.5cm,Space=0.15cm,Space*=0.15cm}

    \defineEasylist{romanlowercasestyle} 
    {Numbers=r,Hang=true,FinalSpace=0.2cm,Align=fixed, 
        Margin1=0.5cm,Margin2=1.5cm,Margin3=2.5cm,Margin4=3.5cm, 
        Margin5=4.5cm,Margin6=5.5cm,Margin7=6.5cm,Space=0.15cm,Space*=0.15cm}

    \defineEasylist{romanuppercasestyle} 
    {Numbers=R,Hang=true,FinalSpace=0.2cm,Align=fixed, 
        Margin1=0.5cm,Margin2=1.5cm,Margin3=2.5cm,Margin4=3.5cm, 
        Margin5=4.5cm,Margin6=5.5cm,Margin7=6.5cm,Space=0.15cm,Space*=0.15cm}

    \defineEasylist{bullet}{Hide=100,Hang=true,FinalSpace=0.5cm,Align=fixed, 
        Margin1=0.5cm,Margin2=1.5cm,Margin3=2.5cm,Margin4=3.5cm, 
        Margin5=4.5cm,Margin6=5.5cm,Margin7=6.5cm,Space=0.15cm,Space*=0.15cm,
        Style1*=\textbullet\hspace{0.25cm},Style2*=$\circ$\hspace{0.25cm},
        Style3*=$\star$\hspace{0.25cm},Style4*=$\mp$\hspace{0.25cm}}

\begin{document}
        \tocloflot
        \section{Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section}
        \lipsum[1]

        \begin{Easylist}[bullet]
            & dog
            && cat
            &&& rabbit
        \end{Easylist}
        \par\bigskip
        \begin{Easylist}[lowercasestyle]
            & dog
            && cat
            &&& rabbit
        \end{Easylist}
        \par\bigskip
        \begin{Easylist}[romanuppercasestyle]
            & dog
            && cat
            &&& rabbit
        \end{Easylist}
        \par\bigskip
        \begin{Easylist}[romanlowercasestyle]
            & dog
            && cat
            &&& rabbit
        \end{Easylist}

        \subsection{Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section}
        \lipsum[1]
        \subsubsection{Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section}
        \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you post a full, yet minimal code that produces your output? With the code you show, all texts should start at the left margin, so there must be something else.

Comment: @Bernard This black rectangle is a page border, not page margins (just info). Text is starting as I defined 3cm from left margin. I want to add 2 cm indentation as shown in desired output. My MWE is page margin settings which I post + some random text. In my original document I have page borders and table in header.

Comment: Oh! I see now. Did you try `\begin{adjustwidth{2cm}{} ... \end{adjustwidth}`, from  `changepage`?

Comment: @Bernard I have posted my MWE + output with `\begin{adjustwidth{2cm}{} ... \end{adjustwidth}`; Is it possible to move numbering to the left, as shown at desired output? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution with the `adjustwidth` environment from `changepage` and `\titlespacing` from`titlesec`. The latter command takes 3 arguments: a first argument to increase or decrease the left margin, the other two for the vertical spacing before and after the title. I incorporated this command at the very beginning of the `adjustwidth` environment, so as to not interfere with the general settings of the document. If this has to be repeated several times in your document, you may consider declaring these modifications in your preamble, with `\AtBeginEnvironment{adjustwidth}{...}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{paper=a4paper}
\geometry{bindingoffset=1.5cm,hmargin={1.5cm,1.5cm},vmargin={1cm,1cm}}
\geometry{includehead=true,headheight=3cm,headsep=1cm}
\geometry{includefoot=false}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}


\lipsum[11]
\begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{\parbox{2cm}{\thesection}}{-0.5pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}{\parbox{2cm}{\thesubsection}}{-0.5pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}{\parbox{2cm}{\thesubsubsection}}{-0.5pt}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{-2cm}{*3.5}{*2.}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{-2cm}{*3.25}{*1.5}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{-2cm}{*3.25}{*1.5}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\lipsum[1]
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit 1* :

Here is a code with the modifications using `titlesec` in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{paper=a4paper}
\geometry{bindingoffset=1.5cm,hmargin={1.5cm,1.5cm},vmargin={1cm,1cm}}
\geometry{includehead=true,headheight=3cm,headsep=1cm}
\geometry{includefoot=false}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\AtBeginEnvironment{adjustwidth}{%
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{\parbox{2cm}{\thesection}}{-0.5pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}{\parbox{2cm}{\thesubsection}}{-0.5pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}{\parbox{2cm}{\thesubsubsection}}{-0.5pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{-2cm}{*3.5}{*2.}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{-2cm}{*3.25}{*1.5}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{-2cm}{*3.25}{*1.5}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\lipsum[1]
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

*Edit 2*:

If have titles that fit on more than one line, and you want them to hang 2cm from the left margin, replace the last (empty) argument of `\titleformat` with a `\parbox`, like this:

```
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\thesection}}{-0.5pt}{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm}}
```

and similarly for sub and subsubsections.

[image]

Comment: first of all, thank you. We had a little bit of missunderstanding, is it possible that numbering (1, 1.1, 1.1.1, etc.) from section/subsection/etc.. is aligned at left margin and data from section/subsection/etc..  is aligned with text (2cm from margin) ? Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: @Beginner:I had seen that, and the code has already been modified  to this aim.

Comment: thank you man, its great! Can you make an edit with example using `\AtBeginEnvironment{adjustwidth}{...}`, thank you :)

Comment: @Beginner: Done!

Comment: is it possible to make indentation(2cm) for second/third/etc.. row in section/subsection/subsubsection/etc.. Im sending a link for picture with red box which needs to be indented https://ibb.co/ewwVyd

Comment: @Beginner: I've added a variant code for `\titleformat`  which does what you want, if I've well understood.

Comment: Can you help me with one thing: `\titlespacing*{\section}{-2cm}{*3.25}{*1}`. As I have understood, in this code *1 is representing spacing after section, and this is working. What is the meaning of *3.25 in this code? I want to make spacing before section/subsec/subsubsec/etc..

Comment: @Beginner: `*n` denotes a length of  `n ex`, with a certain amount of stretchability/shrinkability (see more details at the top of p.5 of the documentation).

Comment: Excellent, thank you :) 
Do you know why after bullet, `before-sep` is not working.. and if I add some random text between, spacing is OK. ? Example: https://ibb.co/fB0Sgy

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code you used. This is probably linked to the list parameters. Perhaps you should post a new question, with the relevant code.

Comment: According to this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442698/combining-two-macros?noredirect=1#comment1110923_442698 and advice from @cfr I have edited your code making it without `adjustwidth`