# Combining two macros

Tags: macros, easylist

Creator of macro `Easylist` is @egreg ([Easylist inside adjustwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442284/easylist-inside-adjustwidth/442294#442294))

```
\makeatletter
\newbox\Easylist@box
\newenvironment{Easylist}
{\par\xdef\Easylist@tpd{\the\prevdepth}%
\setbox\Easylist@box=\vbox\bgroup
\dimen@=\@totalleftmargin
\@parboxrestore
\leftskip=\dimen@
\prevdepth\Easylist@tpd
\begin{easylist}}
{\end{easylist}\xdef\Easylist@tpd{\the\prevdepth}\egroup
\unvbox\Easylist@box\par\medskip\prevdepth\Easylist@tpd}
\makeatother
```

Creator of macro `myeasylist` is @Henri Menke ([Define custom named easylist styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375758/define-custom-named-easylist-styles/375832#375832)) **I have renamed macro; New name is Easylist**

```
\def\defineEasylist#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname 
Easylist@style@#1\endcsname{\NewList(#2)}}
\def\Easylist{\futurelet\next\doEasylist}
\def\doEasylist{\ifx[\next\expandafter\doEasylistone\else\expandafter
\doEasylistnop\fi}
\def\doEasylistone[#1] 
{\begin{easylist}\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\csname 
Easylist@style@#1\endcsname\fi}
\def\doEasylistnop{\begin{easylist}\NewList}
    \def\endEasylist{\end{easylist}}
```

I have used both macros inside my MWE, but it is not working good. I want to use `adjustwidth` inside whole document.
Macro written by @egreg is used for combining `easylist` with `adjustwidth`.
Macro written by @Henri Menke is used for creating custom `easylist` style.

MY MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{changepage}

\makeatletter
\newbox\Easylist@box
\newenvironment{Easylist}
{\par\xdef\Easylist@tpd{\the\prevdepth}%
\setbox\Easylist@box=\vbox\bgroup
\dimen@=\@totalleftmargin
\@parboxrestore
\leftskip=\dimen@
\prevdepth\Easylist@tpd
\begin{easylist}}
{\end{easylist}\xdef\Easylist@tpd{\the\prevdepth}\egroup
\unvbox\Easylist@box\par\medskip\prevdepth\Easylist@tpd}
\makeatother

\def\defineEasylist#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname 
Easylist@style@#1\endcsname{\NewList(#2)}}
\def\Easylist{\futurelet\next\doEasylist}
\def\doEasylist{\ifx[\next\expandafter\doEasylistone\else\expandafter
\doEasylistnop\fi}
\def\doEasylistone[#1] 
{\begin{easylist}\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\csname 
Easylist@style@#1\endcsname\fi}
\def\doEasylistnop{\begin{easylist}\NewList}
    \def\endEasylist{\end{easylist}}

\defineEasylist{lowercasestyle} 
{Numbers=l,Hang=true,FinalSpace=0.2cm,Align=fixed, 
Margin1=0.5cm,Margin2=1.5cm,Margin3=2.5cm,Margin4=3.5cm, 
Margin5=4.5cm,Margin6=5.5cm,Margin7=6.5cm,Space=0.15cm,Space*=0.15cm}

\defineEasylist{uppercasestyle} 
{Numbers=L,Hang=true,FinalSpace=0.2cm,Align=fixed, 
Margin1=0.5cm,Margin2=1.5cm,Margin3=2.5cm,Margin4=3.5cm, 
Margin5=4.5cm,Margin6=5.5cm,Margin7=6.5cm,Space=0.15cm,Space*=0.15cm}

\defineEasylist{romanlowercasestyle} 
{Numbers=r,Hang=true,FinalSpace=0.2cm,Align=fixed, 
Margin1=0.5cm,Margin2=1.5cm,Margin3=2.5cm,Margin4=3.5cm, 
Margin5=4.5cm,Margin6=5.5cm,Margin7=6.5cm,Space=0.15cm,Space*=0.15cm}

\defineEasylist{romanuppercasestyle} 
{Numbers=R,Hang=true,FinalSpace=0.2cm,Align=fixed, 
Margin1=0.5cm,Margin2=1.5cm,Margin3=2.5cm,Margin4=3.5cm, 
Margin5=4.5cm,Margin6=5.5cm,Margin7=6.5cm,Space=0.15cm,Space*=0.15cm}

\defineEasylist{bullet}{Hide=100,Hang=true,FinalSpace=0.5cm,Align=fixed, 
Margin1=0.5cm,Margin2=1.5cm,Margin3=2.5cm,Margin4=3.5cm, 
Margin5=4.5cm,Margin6=5.5cm,Margin7=6.5cm,Space=0.15cm,Space*=0.15cm,
Style1*=\textbullet\hspace{0.25cm},Style2*=$\circ$\hspace{0.25cm},
Style3*=$\star$\hspace{0.25cm},Style4*=$\mp$\hspace{0.25cm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{}
        \begin{Easylist}[bullet]
            & dog
            && cat
            &&& rabbit
        \end{Easylist}
        \par\bigskip
        \begin{Easylist}[lowercasestyle]
            & dog
            && cat
            &&& rabbit
        \end{Easylist}
        \par\bigskip
        \begin{Easylist}[romanuppercasestyle]
            & dog
            && cat
            &&& rabbit
        \end{Easylist}
        \par\bigskip
        \begin{Easylist}[romanlowercasestyle]
            & dog
            && cat
            &&& rabbit
        \end{Easylist}
    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It makes no sense to use `adjustwidth` for the entire document. The whole point of the package is to let you temporarily change the margins from whatever the default is. Using it globally makes no sense.

Comment: Hi @cfr can you check this post please https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/441997/section-and-text-left-indentation. Do you have any other idea how to solve it?

Comment: In the answer there, the assumption is that you have some text outside the scope of the `adjustwidth`. If you only want the section numbers to the left, I'd put them in the left margin and not in the text block itself. If you want the layout Bernard assumes there, that's a different story.

Comment: @cfr I have edited code, thank you! Can you check is everything OK?

Comment: @cfr ToC/LoF/LoT has been moved 2 cm to the right, I have moved them by inserting `\begin{adjustwidth}{-2cm}{}` is it good solution?

Comment: Probably not a good way to do it, no. At least, I wouldn't and I'd expect trouble if I did. But I'm not a good person to advise, since I now see you're using `titlesec`.

Answer (score 2):

With @cfr help

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{paper=a4paper}
\geometry{bindingoffset=1.5cm,hmargin={3.5cm,1.5cm},vmargin={1cm,1cm}}
\geometry{includehead=true,headheight=3cm,headsep=1cm}
\geometry{includefoot=false}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{\parbox{2cm}{\thesection}}{-0.5pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}{\parbox{2cm}{\thesubsection}}{-0.5pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}{\parbox{2cm}{\thesubsubsection}}{-0.5pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{-2cm}{0.6cm}{0.6cm}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{-2cm}{0.4cm}{0.4cm}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{-2cm}{0.2cm}{0.2cm}

\def\defineEasylist#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname 
    Easylist@style@#1\endcsname{\NewList(#2)}}
\def\Easylist{\futurelet\next\doEasylist}
\def\doEasylist{\ifx[\next\expandafter\doEasylistone\else\expandafter
    \doEasylistnop\fi}
\def\doEasylistone[#1] 
{\begin{easylist}\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\csname 
        Easylist@style@#1\endcsname\fi}
    \def\doEasylistnop{\begin{easylist}\NewList}
        \def\endEasylist{\end{easylist}}

    \defineEasylist{lowercasestyle} 
    {Numbers=l,Hang=true,FinalSpace=0.2cm,Align=fixed, 
        Margin1=0.5cm,Margin2=1.5cm,Margin3=2.5cm,Margin4=3.5cm, 
        Margin5=4.5cm,Margin6=5.5cm,Margin7=6.5cm,Space=0.15cm,Space*=0.15cm}

    \defineEasylist{uppercasestyle} 
    {Numbers=L,Hang=true,FinalSpace=0.2cm,Align=fixed, 
        Margin1=0.5cm,Margin2=1.5cm,Margin3=2.5cm,Margin4=3.5cm, 
        Margin5=4.5cm,Margin6=5.5cm,Margin7=6.5cm,Space=0.15cm,Space*=0.15cm}

    \defineEasylist{romanlowercasestyle} 
    {Numbers=r,Hang=true,FinalSpace=0.2cm,Align=fixed, 
        Margin1=0.5cm,Margin2=1.5cm,Margin3=2.5cm,Margin4=3.5cm, 
        Margin5=4.5cm,Margin6=5.5cm,Margin7=6.5cm,Space=0.15cm,Space*=0.15cm}

    \defineEasylist{romanuppercasestyle} 
    {Numbers=R,Hang=true,FinalSpace=0.2cm,Align=fixed, 
        Margin1=0.5cm,Margin2=1.5cm,Margin3=2.5cm,Margin4=3.5cm, 
        Margin5=4.5cm,Margin6=5.5cm,Margin7=6.5cm,Space=0.15cm,Space*=0.15cm}

    \defineEasylist{bullet}{Hide=100,Hang=true,FinalSpace=0.5cm,Align=fixed, 
        Margin1=0.5cm,Margin2=1.5cm,Margin3=2.5cm,Margin4=3.5cm, 
        Margin5=4.5cm,Margin6=5.5cm,Margin7=6.5cm,Space=0.15cm,Space*=0.15cm,
        Style1*=\textbullet\hspace{0.25cm},Style2*=$\circ$\hspace{0.25cm},
        Style3*=$\star$\hspace{0.25cm},Style4*=$\mp$\hspace{0.25cm}}

\begin{document}

        \section{Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section}
        \lipsum[1]

        \begin{Easylist}[bullet]
            & dog
            && cat
            &&& rabbit
        \end{Easylist}
        \par\bigskip
        \begin{Easylist}[lowercasestyle]
            & dog
            && cat
            &&& rabbit
        \end{Easylist}
        \par\bigskip
        \begin{Easylist}[romanuppercasestyle]
            & dog
            && cat
            &&& rabbit
        \end{Easylist}
        \par\bigskip
        \begin{Easylist}[romanlowercasestyle]
            & dog
            && cat
            &&& rabbit
        \end{Easylist}

        \subsection{Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section}
        \lipsum[1]
        \subsubsection{Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section}
        \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It really isn't good to define the spacing around section titles without any glue. (I think that's what you're doing, though I'm not 100% certain I remember what the commands do i.e. maybe the `*` makes a difference or something).  Your page layout looks very odd. Are you feeding `geometry` inconsistent demands? Why is the page cut off at the bottom? You can add `verbose` to get information about the calculation.